# Unexpected icons on desktop

Tags: upgrade, gnome-shell, 19.04, desktop-icons

After updating to the latest 19.04 my desktop, normally clear except for the launcher, filled with icons representing every file in my home directory. Furthermore these 100+ files appear to be completely disordered.

Where are the controls for this?

Comment: Same problem here, but without the update - I just turned on the computer today and the icons appeared. Must be some kind of messed up update of the system. Additionally, my shell (zsh) is terribly slow because of that for some reason and I had to switch to bash temporarily. 

I'd suggest to hang tight and wait for a fix.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of Ubuntu Launchpad, I managed to fix the issue - the problem was that in *~/.config/user-dirs.dirs*, the path of my desktop automatically changed to my home folder. Try to edit the file and see what location points the *XDG_DESKTOP_DIR* constant to.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,

Somehow ~/Desktop had disappeared. So some software obligingly changed the contents of XDG_DESKTOP_DIR to only $HOME/. Restored the directory, fixed ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs,logged off and on and all was fine again.

Keith